# Send changed value of checkbox to php ( in array )

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox

When I click on checkbox (either check it or uncheck it) I want to send its status(on/off) and value of id (or name) to php ( then to sql).
My pseudocode is as follows:

```
  $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
      var cat_id = jQuery(this).attr('name');
      var status = [];

      if($("input:checkbox").is(':checked')) {
          return $(this).attr();
      } else {
          return $(this).attr();
      }

      $.post("var_dump.php", {
          cat_id: status
      }, // should be id(name of chbox) and its value 1-on, 0-off 
      function (response) {
          $("#result").text(response); //just for checking
      });

      return true;
  });
```

I will have many rows with data and check-box for each row (so unchecked box will not count ), I can use `.map()` or `.each()` to build an array  but I want new values every time I change status of check-box - so every time  it should be new `$.post` value.

Reason for array is that I want to make buttons to un-check five or ten (last) check-boxes/rows  so it should be one time array. (but this will be implemented later.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the return statement will not even wait for post code to execute. Remove those unwanted return statements and try this. Also define `status` as a object instead of array since you want to send a key/value pair in the post request.

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function () {
      var cat_id = jQuery(this).attr('name');
      var status = {};
      //This will get the id or name whatever is available
      status[this.id || this.name] = this.checked ? "1": "0";

      $.post("var_dump.php", {
          cat_id: status
      }, // should be id(name of chbox) and its value 1-on, 0-off 
      function (response) {
          $("#result").text(response); //just for checking
      });

      return true;
  });
```